# Using LinearLayout in Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-linearlayout

I have successfully implemented the following code in a simple app that displays a scrollable LinearLayout where a grid_item.xml layout defines the elements of the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
. 
.
.
 <!-- Header --> 
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header" 
   .
   .
   . 
     </LinearLayout>


    <!-- List Divider --> 
     <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="1dip" 
         android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

     <!-- ListView (grid_items) --> 
    <LinearLayout 
          android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
         <ListView 
             android:layout_weight="1" 
             android:layout_width="0dip" 
             android:id="@+id/listview" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
         </ListView>  
     </LinearLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I would like to display variations of my parsed data in different tabs. I have not been able to determine if the Android framework looks for the file named "grid_item.xml" specifically or if I can use a copy of this file under a different name and change the TextView Id's to get the same effect.

(This is my first question on one of a programming board, so I am not even sure if my question is intelligible!)

Thanks in advance.